# Node.js получить json с сайта

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Интересует как забрать **json с сайта** и записать как json

Пример:

```js
const furret = require('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/furret');
```

Comment: возможно Вы имели в виду как получить `json` из *RESTapi*  запроса?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs'); 

const url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/furret";

https.get(url,(res) => {
    let body = "";

    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
        try {
            fs.writeFileSync('poke1.json',body);
            // или если нужно использовать в коде:
            const json = JSON.parse(body);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        }
    });
}).on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
});
```

Comment: нужно дополнить ответ обработчиком ошибок

Answer (score 3):

`npm install node-fetch`

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/furret')
    if(response.status !== 200) throw new Error()
    fs.writeFileSync('poke1.json', await response.text())
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```